# Best practice for storing git tag for version call of API

Tags: git, svn, api-design

I am switching an API from `svn` to `git`, which has created a problem of how to store and present version info of the API to users. Previously I got the version info at time of tag checkout using svn keyword expansion with HeadURL keyword to extract branch or tag name, and I stored it in a file to be read later when a call to /version was made.

I have found through extensive research that `git` doesn't offer an equivalent to `svn` keyword expansion, and the workarounds using `.gitattributes` and filters seem hard pressed to be able to get tag/branch information for a custom keyword substitution.

But APIs presenting version information is the norm, and I'm sure much of them use git for version control. So what would be a good alternative to my problem for storing and presenting version information (tag or branch name) for my API? Or can you offer another way to store branch/tag information in a file at the time of checkout?

Answer (score 0):

An API version is not the same as a commit hash or tag.  For instance, you could have API version 1 that is valid for software versions 0.*, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, and 2.1, but not for 3.0, which switches to API version 2.  Later, software version 2.2 supports both API 1 and API 2.

This means the API version should *not* be defined by the release itself.  Changing the API is a separate operation.  The mapping from release version information (tags or whatever) to supported-set-of-APIs is inherently a part of the code of the release, and therefore is based on the *contents* of (some set of files in) the release, not of the *external number* of the release.  So there's no conflict at all here: you just update the contents as appropriate, and make releases as/when appropriate.